# CollectionView duplicating data after a new post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I cannot seem to figure out why my data keeps duplicating after a new post has been made. When the app starts everything looks as it should and the data is presented properly from `firebase`.

After I make a new post and return to my feed the new data appears but the old data has been duplicated.

Here is my code,

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
   ref.child("brackets").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot)        in


if let bracketsSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for brackets in bracketsSnapshot {
     if let bracketsDict = brackets.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {

     let key = brackets.key
     let post = BracketsPublicFeed(postKey: key, postData: bracketsDict)
     self.posts.append(post)
        }

              }

                    }




                self.collectionView.reloadData()

           })                             

                   }
```

Here is the code used when posted,

```
func PostData(itemToCell1: String, itemToCell2: String, itemToCell3: String, itemToCell4: String, userName: String?/*, userID: String?*/) {

    let ref : FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let votes = 0
    let userName = ""

    let key = ref.child("brackets").childByAutoId().key
        let post = [
            "userID":     userID      as AnyObject,
            "item1":      itemToCell1 as AnyObject,
            "item2":      itemToCell2 as AnyObject,
            "item3":      itemToCell3 as AnyObject,
            "item4":      itemToCell4 as AnyObject,
            "userName":   userName    as AnyObject,
            "votes":      votes       as AnyObject ]


    let childUpdates = ["/brackets/\(key)": post,
    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
    ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)



    }
```

I have tried various things such as,

```
    ref.removeAllObservers()
    self.posts.removeAll()
```

in the `viewDidDisappear`

I will gladly post more code if I am not painting the whole picture.

UPDATE,

Thanks for your responses guys. So far none of them have worked except for the suggestion to use  `ref.child("brackets").removeAllObservers()`

The thing is though it that it works exactly as it should when I write this code,

```
 self.posts.removeAll()
 ref.child("brackets").removeAllObservers()
```

So I get rid of everything and reload it every time the view appears.

Comment: What do you mean duplicate?Can you show before and after JSON of your DB struture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Firebase docs:

> - (void) removeAllObservers
>
> Removes all observers at the current reference, but does not remove any observers at child references.
>
> removeAllObservers must be called again for each child reference where a listener was established to remove the observers.

So, `ref.removeAllObservers()` in `viewDidDisappear` won't remove observer for `ref.child("brackets")`.

Try this in `viewDidDisappear`:

```
ref.child("brackets").removeAllObservers()
```

Comment: To get your idea to work, I did this self.posts.removeAll()
 ref.child("brackets").removeAllObservers()  . What are your thoughts about that solution?

Comment: Yes, That is what i meant . I just didn't mention `self.posts.removeAll()` cause you already had it and it didn't need changing.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `observerSingleEvent`? Seems like you're keep adding new observer every time view appears. There is, actually, neat way to use `FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource` without populating data manually, like this:

```
    dataSource = FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource.init(query: ref.child("brackets"),
            modelClass: Post.self,
            nibNamed: "PostViewCell",
            cellReuseIdentifier: "lesson",
            view: self.collectionView)
```

Comment: What framework is the FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource in? It doesn't pop up. I have Firebase and FirebaseDatabase in that VC

Comment: FirebaseDatabaseUI https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/FirebaseDatabaseUI. And here an example https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/database/DatabaseExampleSwift/PostListViewController.swift (its TableDataSource, but same stuff as Collection)

Answer (score 0):

You're listening for a `.Value` event, which triggers with the **entire list** each time that the data changes (such as when an item is added). So the first time it triggers with e.g. items 1, 2 and 3. Then next time it triggers with items 1, 2, 3 and 4.

You can deal with this in two ways:

- clear the collection view every time
- respond to `.ChildXxx` events instead

The first is simplest, but will lead to a flickering UI. So I'll show the second option: responding to `.ChildAdded`.

A `.ChildAdded` event is fired for every existing child when you first attach the observer. So that's items 1, 2 and 3. When you then add a new item, it will fire **with only item 4**. That allows you to simply add the new item to the collection view:

```
ref.child("brackets").observe(FIRDataEventType.ChildAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let bracketsDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {

    let key = brackets.key
    let post = BracketsPublicFeed(postKey: key, postData: bracketsDict)
    self.posts.append(post)
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
 })
```

*Note: I didn't compile this code, so you may have to fix some problem with it. If you do, leave comments and I'll update.*